# Config transform not working on connection strings in unit test projects

Tags: c#, unit-testing, configuration, msbuild

I have a Visual Studio 2017 unit test project with the following `App.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="SomeKey" value="A" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnection" 
         connectionString="ConnectionToDatabase1" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I then add a transform file calling it `App.Release.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    <add key="SomeKey" value="B" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnection" 
         connectionString="ConnectionToDatabase2" 
         xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

So I expect the value of `SomeKey` to be "B" and the connection string to be "ConnectionToDatabase2".

However when I build my test project in `Release`-configureation I get the following `*.dll.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="SomeKey" value="B" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnection" 
         connectionString="ConnectionToDatabase1" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

So the transform worked on the `appSettings` but not on `connectionStrings`. I even can get the value "B" if I use

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeKey"];
```

Why are the connection strings not transformed?